# Header of the page HTML in PDF

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML page and I want to convert it to PDF, and I have a header of the table that repeats in every page, but how can I know that I arrived at the end of the page to rewrite the header?

Comment: put your code here which you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the browser's capability by pressing `CTRL+P` or `CMD+P`.

---

OR check [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php) when you wish to use PHP.
Here they push using [PrinceXML](https://www.princexml.com).